# Having a hard time adding results together in C (For Loop)

Tags: c

I wrote this code in C. What it basically do is it takes an input (number) for the user and, depending the number the user chose, it will run a `for` loop. The `for` loop will asks the user to input more numbers depending on the statement that it is asking. The code will then take those input from the user and apply it to the formula.

Let say the user inputs 2 at first. What it is supposed to do is go to through the loop twice and take the sum from the first and second time and added them together. Unfortunately, it doesn't do that and will only give back the first result from the loop separated by the second result.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    int i = 0;
    int robotMany = 0;
    int enginePower = 0;
    int resistance = 0;
    int weight = 0;
    int height = 0;

    printf("Depending the numbers of robot that you enter.You will need to do the following\n");
    printf("Engine power\nResistance\nWeight\nHeight\n");

    printf("Enter the amount of robots\n");
    scanf("%d",&robotMany);
    printf("You chose %d robot\n", robotMany);

    //Depending  the user input, it will run # of times.
    for(i = 0; i < robotMany; i++){

        //for loop begins
        printf("Enter the engine power.(1-20)\n");
        scanf("%d", &enginePower);
        printf("Enter the resistance.(1-3)\n");
        scanf("%d", &resistance);
        printf("Enter the weight of the robot\n");
        scanf("%d", &weight);
        printf("Enter the height of Robot.\n");
        scanf("%d", &height);
        int product;
        //take the user inputs and apply it to the formual.
        product = (enginePower + resistance) * (weight - height); 

        printf("This is your total power\n");
        printf("%d\n", product);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have a variable or any code to try to keep a running total. Start with a `total` variable outside the for loop, then each time you calculate a `product` add it to the `total`. Don't forget to print the `total` after the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fundamental logic error in failing to keep a running total for the `product` calculated within each loop iteration.

However you have a larger problem in failing to **validate the return** of `scanf` (or any function you use for user-input). It is critical you validate EVERY user input, and even more so when using `scanf` to avoid invoking *Undefined Behavior* in your code. Why? If the user enters a stray character that does not match the *conversion specifier* in the *format string*, a *matching failure* occurs and character extraction from `stdin` ceases at that point leaving the offending character in the input buffer **unread**. In your case this would result in the same *matching failure* occurring for every  call to `scanf` throughout the remainder of your program.

Take for example the user reaches for the `'2'` key but accidentally taps the `'w'` key instead when entering `robotMany`. Not only does the input for `robotMany` fail, but since the `'w'` is left in `stdin` **unread**, it causes input for `enginePower, resistance, weight & height` to fail as well. (if this occurs within a loop, your loop will likely go spinning out of control until the process is manually terminated)

That is why it is critical to **always validate the return** of any input function, but especially the `scanf` family of functions. To catch and handle any input failure (*matching failure, input failure, or manually generated `EOF`*), just **check the return**, e.g.

```
    if (scanf ("%d", &robotMany) != 1) {    /* VALIDATE EVERY USER INPUT! */
        fputs ("error: invalid input, or user canceled - robotMany\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

On to your logic errors. First, you need a variable to track the sum of each `product` calculated on each trip through the loop. Since it appears this will be a total power, just add a `totalpwr` variable and initialize it to zero (as you have done a good job doing with all your variables), e.g.

```
    int i = 0,
        robotMany = 0,
        enginePower = 0,
        resistance = 0,
        weight = 0,
        height = 0,
        totalpwr = 0;   /* sum of product from each iteration */
```

Now within your loop, you want to add `product` to `totalpwr` each time it is computed, e.g.

```
    /* Depending  the user input, it will run # of times. */
    for (i = 0; i < robotMany; i++) {
        ...
        /* take the user inputs and apply it to the formula. */
        int product = (enginePower + resistance) * (weight - height);

        totalpwr += product;    /* add product to total power */
    }
```

To output the `totalpwr`, you will output the value **after** you exit the loop, e.g.

```
         ...
    }

    /* you output the total power required outside the loop */
    printf ("\ntotal power required: %d\n", totalpwr);

    return 0;
}
```

Putting it altogether in an example (without passing on the correctness of the `product` calculation or the range of values needed) you can do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int i = 0,
        robotMany = 0,
        enginePower = 0,
        resistance = 0,
        weight = 0,
        height = 0,
        totalpwr = 0;   /* sum of product from each iteration */

    /* you only need a single printf (fputs would do due to no conversion) */
    printf ("Depending the numbers of robot that you enter, you will need "
            "to enter:\n\n"
            "  Engine power | Resistance | Weight | Height\n\n"
            "Enter the amount of robots: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &robotMany) != 1) {    /* VALIDATE EVERY USER INPUT! */
        fputs ("error: invalid input, or user canceled - robotMany\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\nYou chose: %d robots\n\n", robotMany);

    /* Depending  the user input, it will run # of times. */
    for (i = 0; i < robotMany; i++) {
        printf ("Enter the engine power.(1-20): ");
        if (scanf("%d", &enginePower) != 1) {   /* validate! */
            fputs ("error: invalid input - enginePower\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        printf ("Enter the resistance.(1-3): ");
        if (scanf("%d", &resistance) != 1) {    /* validate! */
            fputs ("error: invalid input - resistance\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        printf ("Enter the weight of the robot: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &weight) != 1) {        /* validate! */
            fputs ("error: invalid input - weight\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        printf ("Enter the height of Robot: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &height) != 1) {        /* validate! */
            fputs ("error: invalid input - height\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        /* take the user inputs and apply it to the formula. */
        int product = (enginePower + resistance) * (weight - height);
        /* the following outputs the per-loop/per-robot product (you can remove) */
        printf ("  iteration %d product: %d\n\n", i+1, product);

        totalpwr += product;    /* add product to total power */
    }

    /* you output the total power required outside the loop */
    printf ("\ntotal power required: %d\n", totalpwr);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** only one `printf` is required to output multiple lines of output. There is no need to make repeated calls one after the other just to output separate lines. All sequential strings will be concatenated by the compiler)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/robotmany
Depending the numbers of robot that you enter, you will need to enter:

  Engine power | Resistance | Weight | Height

Enter the amount of robots: 3

You chose: 3 robots

Enter the engine power.(1-20): 4
Enter the resistance.(1-3): 2
Enter the weight of the robot: 10
Enter the height of Robot: 31
  iteration 1 product: -126

Enter the engine power.(1-20): 5
Enter the resistance.(1-3): 3
Enter the weight of the robot: 9
Enter the height of Robot: 31
  iteration 2 product: -176

Enter the engine power.(1-20): 3
Enter the resistance.(1-3): 1
Enter the weight of the robot: 8
Enter the height of Robot: 31
  iteration 3 product: -92

total power required: -394
```

You may want to add constraints on the `weight` and `height` entry to prevent a negative power-required result -- but that is left to you. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I really do appreciate it. To be frank, at the moment, there are some functions that I still don't understand from your post but, that my fault. The reason is that I recently started to learn coding(about a month ago) so, I have a long way to go. Just to clarify your answer is not wrong, actually I really did like your explanation , since it have taught me that if I want to apply this code in real application I will need to do something similar as you have explain it from your post.

Comment: @FranciscoEchevarria - we all started at the same place.... Learning C is like eating a whale, you have to take it "one byte at a time". The way you learn is with your editor open in one window, the `man page` for the function your using open in another, and a terminal open to compile and run in. C isn't something you learn overnight, or in a week, or month, or year. It's a journey, not a race. Enjoy the learning. Pay attention to every detail, the memory used, the characters extracted from, or left in  your input stream, every byte counts. You will do fine.